Single Signon SAML certificate Azure config
I’ve been trying to create a powershell script to set the SAML certificate settings  for enterprise applications “sign SAML assertion” to be “true”, I can’t seem to find the setting anywhere, I’ve found the setting in terraform enterprise (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/tfe/latest/docs/resources/saml_settings#want_assertions_signed), there’s a setting optional to have “want_assertion_sigbed”. Has anyone come across this any help would be appreciated. Apologies if this seems a bit all over the place.

Have you consider calling openssl to create the certificate from from a powershell script?  https://faq.miniorange.com/knowledgebase/can-generate-certificate-saml-app/

This issue is when we renew the cert which we would like do programmatically, we are able to do it through the portal. Would OpenSSL allow us to configure this setting, also can it be used in a production environment?

See following https://indigo-iam.github.io/docs/v/current/admin-guide/saml.html

PS is written in Net Library so you can always can use c# code .  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/saml-token-provider

@jdweng thanks for that, but just wondering does that work with app registrations in Azure, when you go into manage -> single sign on -> SAML Certificate -> edit and Sign Assertion (not the best with c#)

This is what I'm trying to achieve rogrammatically https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/enterprise-apps/certificate-signing-options

Here is the openssl method : https://indigo-iam.github.io/docs/v/current/admin-guide/saml.html
